# Как сверстать блок с картинками без position?

Tags: вёрстка

Всем привет. Как сверстать, этот блок, без position, если линии и лайк это разные картинки?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что значит "без position"? Как минимум background-position нужно задействовать, если нельзя разметку ломать. Так что какой-то position использовать всё же придётся.

Answer (score 1):

Ни как. Делаешь две картинки в одном `<div>` Позиционируешь одну относительно другой. Или же совмещаешь обе картинки в одну.